Device tree overlay and shield
I want to use stm32f401_mini together with ssd1306_128x64 shield. The problem is that the ssd1306_128x64 expects that the arduino_i2c node will be defined. Unfortunately the arduino_i2c node is not defined for my board so I thought that it may be a good idea to add something like this:
arduino_i2c: &i2c1 {};

I added it to the device tree overlay however it seems that due to the fact that using the shield also involves loading an overlay, they are like on the same level, so while loading overlay for the shield, my overlay with the above modification is not yet available.
I guess that solving this issue would be to add the above line to board's dts file however I would like to avoid zephyr in tree files and add customisations to my application.
Is there a way to extend / override board's device tree using .dts file in app/boards so that the shield overlay will have required node available?
